# A word or phrase that means to swallow people

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

ln some parts of the world, violent earthquakes sometimes make the ground open up and swallow people. 
My question is: is there a word or phrase to describe this appalling scene?

Comment: You could also try verbing [sarlacc](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sarlacc&oldid=727394937). (On second thought, probably only appropriate in a fictional setting, not when real people are involved.)

Comment: swallowed up, you already have it.

Answer (score 18):

The following biblical passage uses language very similar to your own:

> ***the earth opened its mouth and swallowed them*** and their households, and all those associated with Korah, together with their possessions ([Numbers 16:32](http://biblehub.com/numbers/16-32.htm))

This passage should convince you that there is nothing wrong with *plainly* saying "the earth swallowed the people."

You could also say:

> ***the earth opened its maw*** to swallow them

where ***[maw](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20maw&sourceid=silk&ie=UTF-8)*** means "the jaws or throat of a voracious animal."

You could also say:

> The earth ***devoured*** them

where ***[devour](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20devour&sourceid=silk&ie=UTF-8)*** means "eat (food or prey) hungrily or quickly."

All of these examples ***anthropomorphize*** the earth (that is, depict the earth with human characteristics like having a mouth). There is nothing wrong with this technique and it can be quite effective, especially when combined with evocative words like *maw* and *devour*, which connote viciousness and gluttony.

Comment: The language in the qoute from the Bible is simple and clear. They are the same as those in my post. I was wondering if there is a formal equivalent.Thanks anyway.

Comment: Mido Mido, I've given you other options too. But the reason I gave the bible quote was to convince you that "the earth opened its mouth and swallowed people" can already be construed as a phrase in some sense, given the wild popularity of the bible. It is a phrase *conventionally* used to describe the types of scene you point to.

Comment: You are right. I do agree with you. I am just looking for a strong synonym or phrase.

Answer (score 17):

**Engulf** is a good word for this. American Heritage:

> To swallow up or overwhelm by or as if by overflowing and enclosing: The spring tide engulfed the beach houses.

More generally, a scene like that might be described as a **cataclysm**.

> something that causes great destruction, violence, etc.

(from Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary)

Comment: Good word. So, can we say : Suddenly, the earthquake engulfed all of the houses and people of the village.

Comment: I'd argue that earthquakes don't directly engulf things; the results of an earthquake -- cracks (chasms), sinkholes, mudslides, tsunamis, etc. do.

Comment: Engulf is to surround. This is not a good answer.

Comment: @Lambie Engulf *is* to surround. Surround would *also* be a reasonable answer, if a bit less apt.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe That thinking would apply to all of these answers, as it is the cracks, sinkholes et cetera that do the swallowing as well.

Comment: @DCShannon, Agreed. The OP's question says "is there a word or phrase to describe this appalling scene?" which refers to "ground open up and swallow people" earlier in the question. Then the OP asks (in a comment here) "can we say...the earthquake engulfed all of the houses...". I'm saying "no, you can't say that; earthquakes don't engulf things". The other answers are valid, as long as not applied to the earthquake, but rather to the holes, slides, etc.

Answer (score 3):

[Engulf](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/334969/70061) and [Swallow](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/334967/70061) are good options. For variety, here's another one:

**Envelop**

[from MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/envelop)

> **1:** to enclose or enfold completely with or as if with a covering

[from the Free Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/envelop)

> *tr.v. en·vel·oped, en·vel·op·ing, en·vel·ops*
>   **1.** To wrap, enclose, or cover: *"Accompanying the darkness, a stillness envelops the city" (Curtis Wilkie).*
>
> **2.** To surround: *The troops enveloped the town.*

This term gives a visual of the ground rising up and surrounding the people, much like engulf.

You might say:

> During the earthquake, the ground opened up and enveloped the people.

Note that this is *not* pronounced like 'envelope'. The emphasis is squarely on the second syllable.

Answer (score 2):

The victims were violently devoured by the chasm.

Comment: " devoured by the chasm" is a good expression. Thanks.

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.
For help writing a good answer, see [answer].

Comment: devoured by the chasm is poetic

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest **[subsume](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/subsume)**. It means absorb, and its origin is the latin *subsumere*, whose parts roughly translate to *take from below*.

> Include or absorb (something) in something else

[Example](http://www.digitaljournal.com/article/291862):

> The National Post is reporting that all four members of the
> Prefontaine household have died after their house was subsumed by a
> sinkhole.

To be honest though, I think simply using swallow is more commonly used. If you google "killed sinkhole", you will find article after article saying that some person was swallowed by a sinkhole.

Comment: Yes, but people are not subsumed. Only things.

Comment: @Lambie - I don't agree. People can be subsumed. A search of "he was subsumed" or "she was subsumed" returns many hits of people being subsumed into one thing or another.

Comment: No, people can be subsumed UNDER a list; but people cannot be subsumed by a sinkhole. Your definition says: include or absorb. If you fall into a fault line chasm created by an earthquake,  you are not subsumed. It does not not fly. Swallowed by a sinkhole, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps **entomb**:

> transf. and fig. To enclose as in a tomb; to overwhelm; to bury. Also absol. *OED*

Example usage:

> The earth entombed them / They were entombed by the earth

Alternatively, you could consider figurative usages of consume or ingest, presenting the earth as a living being.